# Separating reads from writes in a sql server based eCommerce site?

Tags: sql-server, architecture, scalability

I work for a ticket re-sale eCommerce site, and one of the problems that we have is that during on-sale periods our database is bombarded with thousands of requests.

the table that holds the tickets is constantly updated and read from and this is a major bottleneck for the site.

We considered reading from replicated databases but these replicated servers are some times hours out of sync.

one Idea was to use triggers on the tickets table and according to Update,Insert,Delete actions populate a denormalized table, and use this denormalized table to do the reads on. this might make queries a bit faster.

We have considered CQRS but due to the nature of our site, and the following reasons we think that it would not be a good fit:

each ticket is unique, since it is uploaded by a seller, and multiple buyers will be competing for the same tickets concurrently.

we experience bursty traffic when popular events are listed, and tickets are sold in a request-response manner.

are there any other techniques that we can use distribute some of the load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you tell us more about which version of SQL Server you are using (2008R2, 2012, edition, etc.) and what Isolation Level are you running? As far as triggers go, they are rarely synonymous with "performance improvement" =)  Have you been able to identify the specific waits in your DB? Are reads waiting on a long-winded update transaction or delete of some sort? Or are you experiencing memory pressure on the db server? Do you have auto update statistics on? Are your writes to the table also bursty? If your stats are out of date, you might be picking up inefficient query plans along the way. If you are not already using it, I'd highly recommend [sp_Blitz](http://www.brentozar.com/blitz/) from Brent Ozar to give you some more insight.

Once you know more about those items, you'll probably have a better idea of whether or not you NEED to actually distribute load vs. just do some tuning.

As far as load distribution, SQL Server AlwaysOn Availability Groups are potentially an answer, though they take some finessing. A readable secondary can be created that is asynchronously replicated which, in my experience at least, generally maintains fairly low latency. A synchronous replica can also be spun up, but that could compound wait issues...you'd have to do a fair amount of testing on that one.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically building another eBay, with the same scaling issues they have.

There are some descriptions of their architecture: http://www.quora.com/What-is-eBays-architecture, http://highscalability.com/ebay-architecture, and many others on google.

Basically though, it comes down to using asynchronous processing whenever possible (learn about queues), and offloading as much from your main database server as possible, having a good real-time search server (which is not your database server), and scale horizontally by moving as much logic as possible into the app layer.

This will require that you give up ACID principals, and embrace eventual consistency.  Eventual doesn't mean hours though, as you learn about queues, you will realize that allowing for a .5 second delay allows MUCH greater scalability.

So, from a back-of-the-napkin architecture, I would suggest you move your search to some fairly real-time search engine (like [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/)), offload most of your metadata to some no-sql platform (like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/), or [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/)) and reserve your database for processing bids against tickets.  These bids shouldn't go straight to the database, but should be put in a queue, which will enforce ordering, and allow another process to execute them against the database.

Any one of these architectural changes will help with your load, but the asynchronous updating will make the biggest difference.

Comment: Oh, and do some caching for the meta-data.  Not ephemeral stuff (like price, or availability), but the stuff like location and